# android how to get the textview really height by textsize that textview height is wrap_content

Tags: android, textview

my textview height is warp_content android it's textsize is 12sp.
now i want to get the `TextView`'s height by calculation
it's more likely this

```
int height = UIUtil.sp2px(18);
```

but i have search some about `TextView`'s properties. it have a includeFontPadding property and defalut true. i don't know whate defaut fontpading top and btoom is.
how can i calculation it. the `TextView` is in adapter item and it changeable. so i can't use measure's ways to get it.
any one can help me?

Comment: show `UIUtil` please

Comment: public static int sp2px(float spValue) {
        final float fontScale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        return (int) (spValue * fontScale + 0.5f);
    }

Comment: if set includeFontPadding="false",it may be normal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680999/what-is-androidincludefontpadding-for

Comment: thanks IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: i will be set includeFontPadding="false" and set padingtop,padingbottom to replace