# How Can i know in advance if TextView will break my text into two lines

Tags: java, android, string, textview, line

I have a string of text which i am going to place in a TextView and animate it into the screen.
I create the TextView progrematically, and i need to know in advance if the string width is wide enough for the TextView to `break it into two lines.

I try to know like this:

```
 private int getLinesCount(String text) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_DIR_LOCATION);
    paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    float width = (float) bounds.width();
    return (int) Math.ceil(width / TextViewContainerWidth);
}
```

However, when i input a string who`s width is close but not over the TextView width, the TextView breaks the line unexpectedly.

For example, if i input a text who`s width is 1057 and the container size is 1066, the methos will return 1 (one line) as expected.

But the TextView breaks the string into two lines.

Does anyone know hoe the textview decides to break the line?

Comment: Does the TextView have any padding? Or perhaps could it have something to do with `includeFontPadding` on the TextView? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680999/what-is-androidincludefontpadding-for).

Comment: Definitely not a best way , but I had similar scenario soI added one extra textview with same properties but with visibility:gone so that it won't impact the layout. Added text in there and called getLineCount() on that hidden view to determine what will be the linecount in actual view that is going to be displayed.  As both have similar properties,paddings and text sizes , it  worked every time.