# How to remove the space before the first letter in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview, android-xml

So I have 3 vertical aligned TextViews. The second one has a larger font size.

Now, if the second TextView holds a string starting with e.g. a 'B' it looks like the View is indented:

[image]

Here's my XML layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView style="@style/TextAppearance.LabelSmall"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1" />

        <TextView style="@style/TextAppearance.LabelBig"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B TextView2" />

        <TextView style="@style/TextAppearance.LabelSmall"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here's the corresponding styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="TextAppearance.LabelBig" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/opensans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/opensans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.LabelSmall" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/opensans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/opensans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
</ressources>
```

Is there any way to make these TextViews look equally indented?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try android:includeFontPadding="false"

Comment: @PankajKumar I did. It changed nothing. Also [it seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590179/8727593) `includeFontPadding` only concerns the text **height**.

Comment: Seems you are right

Comment: Actually problem is with the typography there is pixel set for the other Text e.g. T and B start index is different so if you use T with 48sp you will notice there is no space, so if you know text is hard coded in that case you can use android:paddingStart="-3dp"

Comment: Have you tried putting a margin at the start of the "smaller" `TextView`s?

Comment: The problem is, that the text is dynamic and can change at runtime. So if the large TextView happens to start with a 'T' the smaller ones would be to far on the right.

Comment: I may be wrong about this but I am pretty sure you can measure the size of the text (rather than the `TextView`) and then you can work out the difference and set the margin, at runtime.

Comment: I don't think that's a solvable issue since this "space" is not an error. I believe it has something to do with the size itself. Try setting a smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use three textviews for single line text, just go for the spannable.

Find some info here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: I didn't try that but I don't think it will really solve my problem since the empty space before 'B's would still be there.

Comment: it will solve your problem because when spannable are are set they act as a single text